# error: Not in scope: type variable [Haskell]

Tags: haskell

i want a list of numerical values in my data type

`data Polynomial = Polynomial {xs ::(Num a) => [a] } deriving (Show)`

but i'm still getting this  Error

```
error: Not in scope: type variable ‘a’
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint)

> In Haskell 98, only functions can have type constraints.

In order to do what you want, you can declare `Polynomial` with a type parameter. Then you write functions with the appropriate type constraints.

```
data Polynomial a = Polynomial xs
    deriving (Show)
```

This allows you to construct concrete polynomial types such as `Polynomial Int` or `Polynomial Float` or even `Polynomial String`. A function which operates on your `Polynomial` type can declare constraints on the type parameter. For example a function to add two polynomials can have the following signature:

```
(+) :: (Num a) => Polynomial a -> Polynomial a -> Polynomial a
```

Rinse and repeat as appropriate for each function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `ExistentialQuantification` language extension, you can do this:

```
data Polynomial = forall a. Num a => Polynomial { xs :: [a] }
```

You can also derive Show with `StandaloneDeriving`:

```
data Polynomial = forall a. (Show a, Num a) => Polynomial { xs :: [a] }
deriving instance Show Polynomial
```