# Why is a universally quantified variable not in scope in this Haskell function?

Tags: haskell

I'm sure I've been able to do something similar in other contexts, and I believe this should be possible (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50193090/3096687):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications     #-}

module FDS.Database where

import           Data.Typeable
import           RIO                              (RIO)
-- other imports omitted

cowRecsByMark :: IsCowRec r => CowMark -> RIO FdsEnv [r]
cowRecsByMark markIn = do
  cs <- initCass
  liftIO $ cassGetRecsByMark cs tblName markIn
  where tblName = type2tblName $ typeRep $ Proxy @r
```

But with this code I get:

```
: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘r’                                                                     
   |
24 |   where tblName = type2tblName $ typeRep $ Proxy @r
   |                                                   ^
```

Comment: Turn on ScopedTypeVariables, and add a `forall` to the type signature.

Comment: Thank you - that is the solution. I was just wading through the other thing I often have momentary difficulty with in Haskell: conversion between string types, but that can be solved more easily by hoogle ;-).

Comment: (This is a _universally_ quantified variable, by the way)

Comment: @chi, man, yeah, mathematically i knew that, but I seem to be getting tripped up whenever I come across this in Haskell because of the relationship to `{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}` , but after looking at the wiki page, i now see why it was named that way ... will try to remember that: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard Haskell, type variables cannot have a scope that extends beyond the type signature in which they appear. Any variables which isn't explicitly given a smaller scope with `forall`<sup>1</sup> is presumed to scope over the type signature in which it appears.

This means that variables referenced in different type signatures must be different type variables, regardless of their name. So had you written `Proxy :: Proxy r` instead of `Proxy @r`, this would have been equivalent to `Proxy :: forall r. Proxy r` and you would have received an error about being unable to unify the two type variables. But the compiler's actual complaint was `Not in scope: type variable ‘r’` - why is that?

`TypeApplications` syntax (such as the `@r`), involve writing a type *expression* outside a type *signature*. As such you can't explicitly pass a type *variable* with `TypeApplications` alone, since no type variables are ever in scope outside a type signature.

But the solution is the same as if you had written `Proxy :: Proxy r`. The [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XScopedTypeVariables) extension allows you to have type variables with larger scopes so that you can refer to the same variable across multiple type signatures, and also in type applications.

You can read more in the user guide section I linked, but here's the short version. If you have a type signature accompanying a definition, then any variables which are explicitly `forall` quantified over the whole of the type signature are also in scope throughout the definition. Any use of that type variable name within type expressions contained in the definition will be interpreted as a reference to the outer variable, instead of presumed to be a fresh type variable scoped over just the inner signature.

So to fix your code you need to do 2 things:

1. Add `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`
2. Change your type signature to `cowRecsByMark :: forall r. IsCowRec r => CowMark -> RIO FdsEnv [r]`

---

<sup>1</sup> In completely standard Haskell you can't even explicitly quantify variables with `forall` at all, so this applies to all variables.